# Finding Mixed Numbers In Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel document that has a column with a range of numbers.

Each cell includes 5 different numbers ranging between 1 and 30.

I need a formula that will find a set amount of these numbers in each cell.

For example I have cells below

```
Cell 1: 15, 20, 9, 12, 11

Cell 2: 15, 25, 9, 13, 1

Cell 3: 15, 30, 2, 12, 18

Cell 4: 15, 27, 21, 12, 7
```

Each cell contains the 5 numbers

I now want to find each cell that contains the number 15 and 12.

So it then tells me that cell 1, 3 and 4 have these numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately i only know the basics in excel so have only tried the usual find tool without any success. If I search for either 15 12 or 15, 12 it only finds them if the numbers are directly after one another. Which isn't suitable as this is always different.

Answer (score 1):

`FIND` will search for text, and will return an error if it is not found.
`ISERROR` will test for the error, and we can decide what to do if there is an error or not.
`IF` will allow us to decide on the actions.

Part 1: find 15:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("15",A1)),"","Found 15")
```

Part 2: find 12:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("12",A1)),"","Found 12")
```

Part 3: combine them:

If *found 15*, then test for *found 12*.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("15",A1)),"","Found 15")
```

now take the Found 12, and put it where we have Found 15 ( as we don't need to worry about testing if we didn't find 15)

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("15",A1)),"",IF(ISERROR(FIND("12",A1)),"","Found 12"))
```

and change the text from Found 12 to Found Both

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("15",A1)),"",IF(ISERROR(FIND("12",A1)),"","Found Both"))
```

run this down the list, and it will show **found both** for each line that has a 12 and a 15 in it.

Comment: +1 for logical explanation of how to nest more IF() functions for more words to check

Answer (score 0):

If the data items are values in a single cell separated by commas, you can use AutoFilter to locate the cells with the desired contents.

The trick is to look for sub-strings rather than numerical values.  For example a filter criteria might be CONTAINS:

15,

rather than 15.